# "Cannot find symbol" java code

Tags: java

I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my code. I have created two different files in the same directory, but I keep getting this error. Thanks for any insight.

The first file is:

```
public class CircleDriver{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Circle aCircle = new Circle();

        aCircle.setColor("green");
        aCircle.setRadius(10);
        aCircle.display();

        Double circleArea = aCircle.computeArea();
        Double circumference = aCircle.computeCircumference();

        System.out.println("circle area: " + circleArea);
        System.out.println("circle circumference: " + circumference);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The Second file is:

```
public class Circle{
    public double circumference;
    public double PI = 3.14159;
    public double radius;
    public double area = 0;
    public String color = "";

    public void setColor(String newColor){
        color = newColor;
    }   

    public void setRadius(double newRadius){
        radius = newRadius; 
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("I am a circle");
        System.out.println("my color is " + color);
        System.out.println("my radius is " + radius);
    }

    public double computeArea(){
            return PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public double computeCircumference(){
        return 2 * PI * radius;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the first file, I get this in the command prompt:

```
CircleDriver.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
            Circle aCircle = new Circle();
            ^
  symbol:   class Circle
  location: class CircleDriver
CircleDriver.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
            Circle aCircle = new Circle();
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Circle
  location: class CircleDriver
`2 errors
```

Comment: Are the classes in the same package? If not, you'll need to import `Circle` into `CircleDriver`.

Comment: It is not allowing me to compile the first file. That is what I am struggling to figure out.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's the good question from newbie..

Answer (score 1):

Did you mark your directory as source folder? Also are they in the same package? If not, you should use import.
I have copied your classes in the same package and it is working fine. Output is:

```
I am a circle
my color is green
my radius is 10.0
circle area: 314.159
circle circumference: 62.8318
```

Answer (score 0):

They should be in the **same** package. If not you have to import the `Circle` class with full qualified name (with package name).

In case of eclipse, it compiles all required files. As you are using command line, make sure you compile both `Circle.java` and `CircleDriver.java`, like so:

```
javac -cp . Circle.java CircleDriver.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling the first file first which means the second file Circle is not compiled yet. Try the compiling the second one first and the first one second.

Comment: I have tried that and it still does not work. I even cleaned out my folder to ensure older versions were not somehow being pointed to. I started again and attempted to re-compile the second file, then the first. Same problem, though.

Comment: Try compiling both the files together. javac Circle.java CircleDriver.java

Comment: Thank you. This method worked. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be fine, so i'm assuming that the files are either in different packages, or the compiler cannot see the `Circle.java` class.

The solution to the first problem is:

1. Move both classes to the same package. They must both have the same package declaration at the top(e.g. `package com.mycompany.myapp;`)
2. Import the circle class: `import path.to.circle.clazz.Circle;`
3. Use the fully qualified name: `path.to.Circle circle = new path.to.Circle();`

If it's the compiler, you will need to compile both classes at the same time with the javac command: `javac -cp . Circle.java CircleDriver.java`